# Clarification of sequential compactness theorem with example

Tags: calculus, analysis

> A set of real numbers $S$ is said to be *sequentially compact* provided that every sequence $\{a_n\}$ in $S$ has a subsequence that converges to a point that belongs in $S$.

For clarification, does the definition of *sequentially compact* mean that for all possible sequences $\{a_n\}$ in $S$,  there exists some subsequence $\{a_{nk}\}$  that converges to some number in $S$?

To get to my main question, taken from the chapter 2.4 of the same [advanced calculus textbook](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821847910) is an example that defines the set of real numbers $$S \equiv (0, 2]$$ and then says

> $S$ is not sequentially compact. Indeed, $\{1/n\}$ is a sequence in $S$. This sequence converges to $0$.

Let me make sure I understand this and please correct me if I'm wrong. To determine that $S$ is not sequentially compact, we look for any possible counterexample sequence $\{a_n\}$. We take the limit $\lim_{n\to \infty}\{a_n\}$, and if we can find a subsequence that converges to a value not in $S$, then $S$ is not sequentially compact. Any subsequence would start at an index greater than $n_0$ and so any subsequence will converge to $0$.  In this example,  $\lim_{n\to \infty}\{a_n\} = 0$ for any subsequence $\{a_{nk}\}$, for $k > 0$. Since $0 \notin S$, $S$ is not sequentially compact.

Comment: But you also need to show that no subsequence of {$a_n$} converges to $0$. Can you see what the limit of any subsequence of a convergent sequence is?

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the first question is *yes*. Your argument for the main question is actually correct, since you showed that **no** subsequence converges to a point of $S$, but it’s not true that finding **one** ‘bad’ subsequence is enough to show that $S$ is not sequentially compact. You must show that **every** subsequence fails to converge to a point of $S$.

I’d also phrase the main argument to emphasize when I’m talking about convergence in $\Bbb R$ and when I’m talking about convergence in $S$, but that’s partly a matter of taste. The argument hinges on three facts:

- If a sequence $\sigma$ converges to some $x$ in some space, then every subsequence of $\sigma$ also converges to $x$ in that space.
- No sequence in $\Bbb R$ converges to two different points.
- If a sequence converges in $S$ to some point $x$, then it also converges to $x$ in $\Bbb R$.

Here $\sigma=\left\langle\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\rangle$, which converges to $0$ in $\Bbb R$, so every subsequence of it also converges to $0$ in $\Bbb R$. If $S$ were sequenctially compact, $\sigma$ would have to have a subsequence converging to some $x\in S$, but then in $\Bbb R$ that subsequence would converge both to $0$ and to $x\ne 0$, which is impossible.

**Added:** Note that there are other ways for a set $S\subseteq\Bbb R$ to fail to be sequentially compact. For example, $S=\Bbb Z$ fails because the sequence $\langle n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ in $S$ has no convergent subsequence even in $\Bbb R$, so it certainly has none in $S$.

Comment: Hi, according to your first bullet, if a sequence converges to $x$, then all its sub-sequences should also converge to $x$. But is it true vice-versa too? If a sub-sequence converges to a point $x$, will the sequence also converge to that point $x$? If that was true, then the definition of sequential compactness could just have been defined in terms of convergence of a sequence.
I am really confused about this part. Is there any example, where convergence of a subsequence (and not of the sequence) leads to sequential compactness?

Comment: @Khushboo: No, it’s quite possible for a sequence $\sigma$ that doesn’t converge to have a subsequence that converges. For instance, just let $x_n=(-1)^n$: the subsequence $\langle x_{2n}:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $1$, but the original sequence is clearly not convergent.

Comment: Thanks for the example. I understand that its possible. But, can you tell me how is it helpful in determining sequential compactness? I am having trouble getting intuitive understanding of this concept.

Comment: @Khushboo: A space is sequentially compact if it does *not* contain a sequence with no convergent subsequences. In $\Bbb R$, for instance, we have the sequence $\langle 1,2,3,4,\ldots\rangle$: none of its subsequences converges, so $\Bbb R$ is not sequentially compact. In the problem in the original question here, the sequence $\langle 1,\frac12,\frac13,\frac14,\ldots\rangle$ has no convergent subsequence **in the space** $S$, so $S$ is not sequentially compact. A sequence in a sequentially compact space need not converge, and it may have many non-convergent subsequences as well, but every ...

Comment: ... subsequence will have a further subsequence that *does* converge.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have it quite right. To show that the set is **not** sequentially compact we need to exhibit a sequence $(a_n)$ such that **no** subsequence of $(a_n)$ converges to a point in $S$. The sequence $(\frac{1}{n})$ does have that property, since in fact all subsequences converge to $0$, which is not in $S$.

Comment: Andre: $S = (0,2]$ does not include $0$.

Comment: Yes, I did not stress that it was outside, since OP knew that. I was concentrating on the logic, and saying that one has to check that no subsequence converged to something inside (trivial in this case, since all subsequences converge to the same thing).